# Problem with LAN multiplayer game in Unity

Tags: unity

I'm trying to learn how to make an offline LAN multiplayer game in Unity.

So for example, I make something that can send a text message and make a cube XD

Now this is my problem:

[image]

(When I send a message, try connecting to the server, or when I try to create a cube I should first click on the other window!)

StartServer:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class StartServer : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform Taghsimobj;
    public Transform Makan;
    public Transform CubeOBJ;

    public string MSG; 
    public string ResMsg;

    void Ress (string inres) {
        ResMsg = inres;

    }

    void OnGUI () {

        if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Disconnected)
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button ("StartServer"))
            {
                Network.InitializeServer(10, 25000);
            }
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Connect"))
            {
                Network.Connect ("192.168.1.101", 25000);
            }

        } 
        else 
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button ("CreatCube"))
            {
                Network.Instantiate (CubeOBJ, Makan.transform.position, Makan.transform.rotation, 0);
            }
            if (GUILayout.Button ("CreatChat"))
            {
                Network.Instantiate (Taghsimobj, this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation, 0);
            }
            if (GUILayout.Button ("SendMessage"))
            {
                GameObject.Find ("GameObject(Clone)").GetComponent<NetworkView>().RPC ("ResText", RPCMode.All, MSG);
            }
            MSG=GUILayout.TextField(MSG);   
            GUILayout.Box (ResMsg);
        }


    }
}
```

taghsim:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Taghsim : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
    }

    [RPC]
    void ResText (string ResIn) {
        GameObject.Find ("Main Camera").SendMessage ("Ress", ResIn);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should not be sorry for your English.

Comment: Did you try to test it with _two_ computers? And did you try to run a debugger on that? The issue you're displaying seems related to the fact that your second window does not update the _graphics_ because it's not on focus rather than related to network handling.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see when you are not focusing a game instance, it goes to paused state

You must use:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-runInBackground.html